# NSMutableArray inside NSMutableDictionary how to filter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, predicate

I have an NSMutableDictionary that contains key=>obj, these objects are NSMutableArray each one of these NSMutableArray have many objects of Person class:

Person class have id,name,age

```
NSMutableDictionary => key(A)=>NSMutableArray (person_1,person_2)
NSMutableDictionary => key(H)=>NSMutableArray (person_3,person_5)
```

How i can find an object of person inside the NSMutableDictionary that has an id of 6 or name of "Tony" using Predicate filter !!

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Maybe a Google search?

Comment: very difficult to form a logic, Sorry I can't.

Comment: Here's a link you might find useful: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 NSArray *persons = [dictionary allValues];
 NSArray *allPersons = [persons valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id == %@) OR (name CONTAINS[cd] %@)", persionId, personName];

 NSArray * resultArray = [allPersons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Amazing Akhilrajtr, the solution you provided works exactly how i want it. but I have one question can we know in which NSMutableArray of [dictionary allValues] this object is found ?

Answer (score 0):

Assumption about your structure.

```
{
    "A": [
        "aaa_Persion...",//It indicate Person Object which contain id, name.
        "abc_Person...."
    ],
    "H": [
        "h_Person..........."
    ]
}
```

If your structure is same as above, Following code will help you..

```
for(NSArray *array in yourIndexDictinary)
    {
      NSArray *searchedPerson =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id == %@) || (name CONTAINS[cd] %@)",searchId,searchString];
    }
```

> Note: [cd] means, String comparisons are by default case and diacritic
>   sensitive.